# Campos opcionales en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Estoy validando unos campos y funciona bien, exceptuando un campo que es opcional, me pide que cumpla las reglas si están vacíos en el formulario. Esto es lo que tengo:

```
{
        public function update(Request $request, $alias){
            if($request->password != ''){
            $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],

                'lastname' => 'required',
                'address' => 'required',
                'postalcode' => 'required',
                'country' => 'required',
                'city' => 'required',
                'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
                'identification' => 'required',
            ],[
                'name.required' => 'El campo nombre es obligatorio',
                'email.required' => 'El campo correo electrónico es obligatorio',
                'lastname.required' => 'El campo apellido es obligatorio',
                'address.required' => 'El campo dirección es obligatorio',
                'postalcode.required' => 'El campo código postal es obligatorio',
                'country.required' => 'El campo país es oblogatorio',
                'city.required' => 'El campo ciudad es obligatorio',
                'identification.required' => 'El campo identificación es obligatorio'
            ]);
        }else {
            $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
                'lastname' => 'required',
                'address' => 'required',
                'postalcode' => 'required',
                'country' => 'required',
                'city' => 'required',
                'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
                'identification' => 'required',
            ], [
                'name.required' => 'El campo nombre es obligatorio',
                'email.required' => 'El campo correo electrónico es obligatorio',
                'lastname.required' => 'El campo apellido es obligatorio',
                'address.required' => 'El campo dirección es obligatorio',
                'postalcode.required' => 'El campo código postal es obligatorio',
                'country.required' => 'El campo país es obligatorio',
                'city.required' => 'El campo ciudad es obligatorio',
                'identification.required' => 'El campo identificación es obligatorio'
            ]);
        }

        $u = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
            $u->email = $request->email;
            $u->name = $request->name;
            $u->lastname = $request->lastname;
            $u->identification = $request->identification;
            $u->address = $request->address;
            $u->postalcode = $request->postalcode;
            $u->country = $request->country;
            $u->city = $request->city;
            $u->password = Hash::make($request->password) ? bcrypt($request->get('password')) : $u->password;

            $u->save();

            return back()->withSuccess('Tu actualización se ha realizado con exito');
        }
```

Quiero hacer que el campo password sea opcional al momento de que un usuario intente actualizar sus datos, pero me sigue saliendo que tengo que llenar ese campo, me podrian ayudar porfavor.

Estoy usando laravel 8

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero te recomiendo usar [Form Request](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#form-request-validation) para hacer las validaciones.

Entiendo que la regla que requieres para 'password' en el método `update()` la hace siempre opcional.

Para hacer el código un poco más legible compone los arrays de reglas y mensajes por separado y luego pásalos a `validate()`:

```
$rules = [
    ...
];
$messages = [
    ...
];
$request->validate($rules, $messages);
```

Una vez tienes el conjunto de reglas puedes añadir la de `password` en base a un condicional. Empieza por usar el método `has()` del objeto `$request` para ver si tienes el dato de contraseña:

```
$rules = [
    ...
];
$messages = [
    ...
];

if ($request->has('password') && $this->password) {
    $rules['password'] = ['string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'];
}
$request->validate($rules, $messages);
```

En este caso no hace falta la regla 'required', ya sabes que esta y tiene contenido.
En caso de que quieras añadirlo directamente con el resto de reglas, como quieres que sea opcional no debes usar 'required' sino indicar que puede no tener valor con 'nullable':

```
$rules = [
    'password' => ['nullable', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ...
];
$messages = [
    ...
];
$request->validate($rules, $messages);
```

#### Notas Adicionales

Las reglas pueden cambiar cuando se crea o actualiza un registro.

Si se usan validaciones directamente en los métodos `store` y `update` del controlador, deben ajustarse en los propios métodos.

Si se usan *Form Request* puede usarse una clase diferente para cada acción, si hay muchas reglas comunes, puede usarse un trait para contenerlas y ponerlas en comun en ambas clases.

Si se usa un solo *Form Request* para crear y editar, puede usarse el 'método' de la *request* para indicar las reglas que cambian en casa caso:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ];
    if ($this->_method === 'PUT') {
        $rules['title'] = ...;
    }

    return $rules;
}
```